# determine the Reason for Pod Failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a broken pod in default namespace. I want to store associated error events to a file error.txt. I need to use the -o wide output specifier with my command.
I saw command like this

```
- kubectl get pod termination-demo -o go-template="{{range
   .status.containerStatuses}}{{.lastState.terminated.message}}{{end}}"
```

but i need to use -o wide command.

Comment: I dont understand. You say you have to use the `-o wide`. Then use it. Are you facing a problem in using it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue here? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the pod state :

```
kubectl get pod -n <NAMESPACE> <POD> --output=wide -o go-template="{{range.status.containerStatuses}}{{.lastState.terminated.message}}{{end}}" > pod.err
```

Verify by :

```
$ cat pod.err
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you looking to achieve:

if your goal is to get the content into a file you can redirect the output to a file:

```
kubectl get pod termination-demo -o go-template="{{range.status.containerStatuses}}{{.lastState.terminated.message}}{{end}} > error.txt
```